# Need Help Creating Variable with ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

My CSV file (olympics) has 7 variables: name, nationality, sex, sport, gold, silver, bronze. I want to create a new variable called "medal" that basically says gold, silver,bronze = 1, no medal = return 0.

My code:

```
olympics$medal <- ifelse(olympics$gold, olympics$silver, olympics$bronze == gold|silver|bronze, 1, 0)
```

I get this error message: Show in New Window

> Error in ifelse(olympics$gold, olympics$silver, olympics$bronze == gold |  :
> unused arguments (1, 0)

Comment: This is completely invalid R syntax, both for the ifelse statement and for comparison.

Comment: :( which parts need to be adjusted and how should I? Sorry I'm new

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ifelse`. Assuming that `gold`, `silver` and `bronze` are numeric (number of each medal type), then you can just add them together, check if the total is greater than 0 - which will return TRUE/FALSE - and then convert that to numeric (0/1):

```
olympics$medal <- 
  as.numeric(
    (olympics$gold + olympics$silver + olympics$bronze) > 0
  )
```

Or, using `ifelse`:

```
olympics$medal <- 
  ifelse(
    dt$gold > 0 | dt$silver > 0 | dt$bronze > 0, 1, 0
  )
```

Comment: That worked, thank you sir! My professor asked me to use ifelse, but your way seems easier.

Comment: It's also easy using `ifelse`. I have updated my answer.